# Выделение памяти для элемента бинарного дерева

Tags: c

Подскажите, правильно ли я выделяю память для элементов бинарного дерева?

```
if (btree == NULL) {
    btree = (struct binary_tree*) malloc(sizeof(struct binary_tree));
    btree->word = (char*) malloc(strlen(word)+1);
    strcpy(btree->word, word);
    btree->count = 1;              
}
```

Есле структура бинарного дерева такова

```
struct binary_tree{
       char* word;
       int count;
       struct binary_tree* left;
       struct binary_tree* right;
};
```

Пишет ошибку сегментации (любимая ошибка моя :). btree - указатель на структуру.

Comment: можно ли побольше кода? сделал тестовый пример с такими же частями, как у Вас, вроде работает и в gcc и в msvc, но не ручаюсь за правильность. И покажите как и где описан btree, есть ли инициализация

Comment: @mrexox: А в какой строчке падает? Чему равны переменные, которые упоминаются в этой строчке?

Кстати, а вы не забыли инициализировать `left` и `right`?

Comment: Если падает в приведенных строках, то проблема с `word` (например 0). 

Тогда падает в `strlen(word)`.

Но проще всего смотреть в отладчике, предварительно оттранслировав с ключем `-g`. В gdb, например, поможет  команда *where*.